# Django version 3.1.3 form not saving to model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-3.1

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpNI1BBH5IA&list=PLpyspNLjzwBnGesxJOt_0r4xTWR80j7Y3&index=7&ab_channel=CodeWithStein)

I have gone back and written the code to match exactly. I have another form that works called *category_add* which is exactly the same as this form. But for the life of me I cannot figure out why *bookmark_add* doesn't update the database with the form entries.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Bookmark(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='bookmarks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bookmarks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**View.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .forms import BookmarkForm


@login_required
def bookmark_add(request, category_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookmarkForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            bookmark = form.save(commit=False)
            bookmark.created_by = request.user
            bookmark.category_id = category_id
            bookmark.save()
            return redirect('category', category_id=category_id)

    else:
        form = BookmarkForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'bookmark/bookmark_add.html', context)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Bookmark


class BookmarkForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bookmark
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'url']
```

**Urls.py**

```
    path('', dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('categories/', categories, name='categories'),
    path('categories/add/', category_add, name='category_add'),
    path('categories/<int:category_id>/', category, name='category'),
    path('categories/<int:category_id>/add_bookmark', bookmark_add, name='bookmark_add')
]
```

**bookmark_add.html**

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Add link</h1>

    <form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button type="submit" class="button is-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What happens when you click the submit button?  Do you get redirected to the `category` view?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I am redirected to category just fine as if everything worked. But category that should now have my new saved data doesn't have anything in it. When I login as admin (superuser) there is nothing saved in my bookmarks.

Comment: Well, if you're getting redirected to `category`, then it certainly seems like _something_ was saved to the database.  I'm not really up to speed on django ModelForms, but I see in the class definition of `BookmarkForm` that fields is set to only `title, description, url`.  Does that mean only those fields are saved?  If so, how would it link that bookmark to a particular user?

Comment: BookmarkForm is using django's form mechanism to populate a from in my html based off of those selected entries. This isn't used for saving, but if you look at my view.py I have the form = BookmarkForm(request.POST) and the lines under them that handle the data and assign the user to the data (i.e created_by).

Comment: After calling save(), `bookmark.pk` should be populated.  Can you log that value, and then look up that entry in the database to see if it has anything which would explain the issue?

Comment: There are no entries under bookmark. The only entry there is the one that I created using django's admin portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this!

This was a dumb issue and an oversight on my end. Thanks to the content creator on youtube. I just needed to append "/" to the url path for add_bookmark.

**Problem:**
`path('categories/<int:category_id>/add_bookmark', bookmark_add, name='bookmark_add')`

**The Fix:**
`path('categories/<int:category_id>/add_bookmark/', bookmark_add, name='bookmark_add')`